# Rendering 404 in sinatra if file not found

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I have a basic sinatra app that renders files from a directory. What I'd like is returns 404 if page does not exist. Currently it raise 500 error.

```
get '/:page' do
  erb :"pages/#{params[:page]}", layout: :"layouts/application"
end
```

Answer (score 26):

Try this ;)

```
# 404 Error!
not_found do
  status 404
  erb :oops
end
```

Make yourself a 404 page with whatever name you like (mine is `oops.erb`, for example), and this should work just fine.

`not_found` is **Sinatra's** error-handling helper for grabbing error 500s and 404 not-founds that it returns. You can then change the HTTP status and corresponding view using it. [Check out the documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Error%20Handling) for all of Sinatra's error handler's: they're super useful!

Comment: Also, [check out Sinatra's `halt`](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/01/why-sinatras-halt-is-awesome).

Comment: If you use `halt(404)` as suggested by Jordan, `not_found` will be automatically called (and you don't even need to specify the `status` directive).

Comment: However, note that in my experience - contrary to what the original answer is suggesting - `not_found` only catches 404s. It won't be invoked for 500s or even other errors in the 4xx class.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
get '/:page' do
  requested_erb = File.join(root, 'pages', params[:page])

  pass unless File.exists?(requested_erb)

  erb :"#{requested_erb}", :layout: :"layouts/application"
end
```

I haven't tested this, so there might be some issues with the above code, but that's the general idea in my head.

Comment: Unfortunately all pages now raise 404

Comment: Check to see what `requested_erb = File.join(root, 'pages', params[:page])` returns - this may not be 100% correct.